# Is self ever used in returning a reference to a class in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I am working through a book on Cocoa and Objective-C.  One example has stumped me:

```
- (id) currentObject {
   return [Photo photo];
}

- (void) checkObjectType {
    id object = [self currentObject];
    ...
}
```

In this case, checkObjectType calls currentObject.  currentObject then returns an instance of Photo, however, it's creating a new instance of Photo and returning this reference, is it not ?  Isn't it not return a reference to itself ?  I was expecting something like:

```
return self;
```

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be referring to Scott Stevenson's book. The example given is just trying to show how to use the `isMemberOfClass:` method. I wouldn't read any more into it than that.

Your confusion is understandable. As you've already figured out, the `currentObject:` method returns a newly-created autoreleased object, *not* the object itself as its name would imply. It's a poorly named method. Maybe it's just a sneaky way of reminding the reader to name methods appropriately. :)

Comment: Wow!  I'm impressed - you knew that was Stevenson's book from that snippet of code ?  You must have a good memory.  Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I am probably going to jack this up but here goes...

Your code snippet is within a class. That class has a method called `currentObject` that returns a `Photo` object.

> id object = [self currentObject];

This is asking the current class `self` to call the method `currentObject` which just so happens to be a `Photo` object. Take that photo object and assign it to `object`

If the section of the book is discussing the type `id` then this seems to be a static example for method that is designed to show how an `(id)` method like `currentObject` could return any kind of object.

Maybe a better example would have been:

```
- (id) currentObject:(NSString *)someKey {
   return [someDictionary objectForKey:someKey];
}

- (void) checkObjectType {
    id object = [self currentObject:@"photo"];
    ...
}
```

Where someDictionary contained a variety of objects like a NSString, Photo and NSURL. The `currentObject` could handle them all.

Comment: Ok.  I get your point about the id variant type.  What do you mean when you say "static example" ?

Comment: If the method was only ever going to return a Photo object IMHO it would be defined as a such: - (Photo) currentObject {...} If it were to return an object where the programmer would not know what the specific object was, it could be defined as - (id) currentObject {...} because (id) allows it to handle any object. In the case of the book, the author may not have wanted to address it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `currentObject` is returning the result of `[Photo photo]`. Assuming that normal Cocoa naming conventions are being followed, `Photo` is a class (because it begins with a capital letter), so `+photo` is a class method that (presumably) returns an instance of the `Photo` class. Because the method name does not contain `alloc` or `copy`, we can further deduce that  it returns an autoreleased object.

The "currentObject" method name is certainly confusing in this instance, but doing this:

```
- (id) currentObject {
   return self;
}
```

would be completely pointless: `[self currentObject]` would just be the same as saying `self`